# Java generics: creating collections of class objects extending Throwable

Tags: java, generics

Why does the first line work, but the second one doesn't?

```
Collection<Class<? extends Throwable>> exs =
    new ArrayList<Class<? extends Throwable>>() {{ add(MyOwnException.class); }};
Collection<Class<? extends Throwable>> exs = Arrays.asList(MyOwnException.class);
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason it's an error is that java is inferring the wrong type, but you can make it compile, *without casting*, by specifying the type in the call to the typed method [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

```
Collection<Class<? extends Throwable>> exs 
    = Arrays.<Class<? extends Throwable>>asList(Exception.class); // compiles
```

Without specifying the type, java infers the element type of the collection to be `Class<Exception>`, which is *not* assignable to `Collection<Class<? extends Throwable>>`.

Remember with generics that if `B` extends `A`, `List<B>` does **not** extend `List<A>`.

Comment: +1, but I have a question. Why doesn't a local variable defined as `Class<? extends Throwable> clazz` do the trick in `Arrays.asList(clazz)`?

Comment: @Raffaele Because the type is inferred from the parameter of `asList` as `Class<MyOwnException>`, but you need it to be different

Comment: Actually the Eclipse compiler says `List<Class<capture#1-of ? extends Throwable>> to List<Class<? extends Throwable>>` , it doesn't mention `Class<Exception>`, but I can't interpret the *capture#1* part...

Answer (score 3):

Generics are very tricky.

In this case `Arrays.asList` will return a `List<Class<MyOwnException>>`, which is not the same than `List<Class<? extends Throwable>>`.

Their behavior will differ since the type `List<Class<? extends Throwable>>` would allow you to add objects that extend Throwable but `List<Class<MyOwnException>>` only accept objects of type MyOwnException.

Comment: That's not true they have to be "exactly the same": `List<?> x = new ArrayList<String>();` compiles, as does `List<? extends Number> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: You are right, Bohemian, I just corrected the second part, which wasn't true. Bad hours to answer quickly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first line works because the type of the element of the **right side** of the assignement (of the `ArrayList`) is `Class<? extends Throwable>` that allows to add any kind of `Class<? extends Throwable>` object, including your `MyOwnException`. You could also add to the first line `Collection` an `Exception.class` or a `NullPointerException.class`, etc.

But the second line is much stricter: you have a `Collection<Class<? extends Throwable>>` that might contain a `Class<Exception>`, a `Class<NullPointerException>`, etc. and you want to put in place a `Collection<Class<MyOwnException>>` that don't allows for `Class<Exception>`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList(MyOwnException.class)` is inferred to have type `List<Class<MyOwnException>>`, which is not compatible with `List<Class<? extends Throwable>>` since the type parameters are different.

If you put a wildcard at the first-level, it should work:

```
Collection<? extends Class<? extends Throwable>> exs = Arrays.asList(MyOwnException.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second example were to work, it would allow for code like this:

```
Collection<Class<? extends Throwable>> exs = Arrays.asList(MyOwnException.class);
exs.add(IOException.class);
```

See the problem? `Arrays.asList()` would return a `List<Class<MyOwnException>>`, and then you'd be trying to insert a `Class<IOException>` into that. That's obviously a type mismatch.